# Sync extension PHP - shm_open() is not available on this platform

Tags: php, shared-memory, pecl

I have a problem when I try to install the Sync extension of PHP with the command `pecl install sync` on my mac.

Here is the error I get from the command :

```
checking for shm_open in -pthread -lrt... configure: error: shm_open() is not available on this platform
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/sync/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config' failed
```

I have `MacOS Catalina 10.15.6`.

I really can't find a solution to this problem on the internet. Has anyone ever had this problem and been able to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem was. It did not work through pecl, [you need to do it through phpize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php).

You can download [the sync module sources here](https://pecl.php.net/package/sync).

It needs to be manually compiled.

After executing the "phpize" command, the "configure" file will appear in this folder - you need to edit it. It is necessary to remove all lines "-lrt" in it.

Next, we execute "./configure".

If everything is fine, then we execute "make".

The "modules" folder will be created, it contains two files - "sync.la" and "sync.so". You need "sync.so"

The "make install" command is optional, it will give an error.

You need to manually move or in php.ini set the full path to "sync.so".

It will look something like this:

extension=/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.2/sync/sync-1.1.2/modules/sync.so

I don't know yet if there will be any errors, but I did it. It seems like it even works.

[Opened this issue](https://github.com/php/pecl-system-sync/issues/6), maybe they will fix the problem.